# Back references start on new line when using apacite

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, back-referencing, apacite

When I use the `backref` option in the `hyperref` package along with `apacite` (with the `natbibapa` option), the backrefs appear on a newline. How to prevent this from happening?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
author = {FirstAuthor, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha Title}
}
@misc{A02,
author = {SecondAuthor, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Beta Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\citet{A01} ;\citet{A02}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

### Update

`apacite` places `\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}` after each entry in the `.bbl` file. If I remove all instances of `\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}`  (and then re-compile the `.tex` file via pdflatex), the extra line is removed. This workaround is a solution, but it would probably be better if I re-defined `\PrintBackRefs` or  `\CurrentBib` (I am not sure what one is causing the line break).

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure why, but this helps:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand*{\PrintBackRefs}[1]{}%
}
```

In case you would like to remove the additional white space in front of the back references, you can use

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand*{\PrintBackRefs}[1]{\unskip}%
}
```

Last but not least, in case you would like to enclose the back references in square brackets, add

```
% Enclose the back references in the bibliography in square brackets
% (Econometrica style):
\let \backreforig \backref
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{[\backreforig{#1}]}
```

[image]

Here is a complete compilable example:

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !BIB program = bibtex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
author = {FirstAuthor, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Alpha Title}
}
@misc{A02,
author = {SecondAuthor, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Beta Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backref=page, colorlinks]{hyperref}
% Enclose the back references in the bibliography in square brackets
% (Econometrica style):
\let \backreforig \backref
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{[\backreforig{#1}]}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand*{\PrintBackRefs}[1]{\unskip}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\citet{A01}; \citet{A02}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```